# Retrieving message from proper Resource Bundle using JSF Custom Validation

Tags: spring, jsf

I am using JSF custom validator to fetch an error message from proper resource bundle.

The syntax used is

```
<myCustom:regexValidator regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\/\-\. ]*$"
                            validationMessage="#{resourceBundle['name.format.error']}" />
```

Now what happens is, the error message returned is always fetched from Messages_en_US.properties file.

How do I fetch the message from Messages_ar_AE.properties file? Is there a place where i need to set the Locale, for the application to identify the correct Resource Bundle file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using Spring and JSF, the statment

```
<myCustom:regexValidator regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\/\-\. ]*$"
                            validationMessage="#{resourceBundle['name.format.error']}" />
```

Spring Framework would look for the key 'name.format.error' in messages.properties file defined in the classpath; As by default the locale is identified as English, unless changed otherwise using LocaleResolver.

To fetch the message from appropriate resource bundle the locale has to be set in `'org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver' setLocale method`

This would help Spring framework point to appropriate resource bundle.

Thanks.